# Global array in next.js or react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to define a global array that I can set in `getserverprops` and use throughout the project. Is this possible in next js?

I'm going to  use this  array as a  cache

Comment: Nice idea! But I think you need to have some kind of persistence layer for that. Depending on your environment you could maybe use a sqlitedb or if you are working in the cloud then you can use for example a DynamoDB or Redis in AWS. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

- You can use a global variable on the server ([`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props)),
  and
- you also can use a global variable on the client (aka. the browser),
  but
- you **can not** use the same global variable on the server and the client.

### Server only

If you only ever want to access that variable inside `getServerSideProps`,
then that is theoretically possible, but likely will cause all sorts of problems. E.g. consider a load balancer and 3 different server instances,
which have 3 different caches.

Better would be to use some "established caching technology", like a Redis DB.

### Shared values

As said, you **can not** share a variable between server and client.

You might *(as a mental model)* consider `getServerSideProps` to be executed in a different country
on some secured server which you don't have access to, while the rest of the components *(not all of them)*
are executed on your computer in your browser.

So if you want to share some state between client and server, you need to **create an API** on the server, and communicate between client and server through this API.

If you just define a global array, that array will be created and can be used, but it will be created independently on the server and on the client, i.e. they will be two completely different variable.

`my-app/global.js`:

```
export const globalVariable = {
    trace: [],
};
```

Then you access this variable inside the index.tsx:

`my-app/pages/index.jsx`:

```
const Home = ( props ) => {
    console.log('Client: globalVariable', globalVariable);
    console.log('Client: pageProps:', props);

    useEffect(() => {
        globalVariable.trace.push('from MyApp');
    }, []);

    return null;
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    globalVariable.trace.push('from getServerSideProps');
    return {
        props: {
            serverVariable: globalVariable,
        },
    }
}
```

Then you will have one `globalVariable` on the client, and a separate `globalVariable` on the server.
You will never see `"from getServerSideProps"` on the client, you will never see `"from MyApp"` on the server.

You can pass `globalVariable` from the server as `props`, like I did with `serverVariable: globalVariable`,
and that value will be available on the client, but it will be a *third* new variable on the client side.
You can not hope to `props.serverVariable.trace.push('pushed from client to server')`, that will only push
to the new client variable.